# why does my website appear inside a <frameset>?

Tags: web, frameset

I have a website (just for my own references, nothing interesting for the public.)

When I load my page ([Test Page](http://marrowbrook.com/TestFiles/testpage.htm)) inside IE9 and view the source of the page - I can see the HTML as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="body">
    Simple test page, with an image. <br />
    <img src="http://www.w3.org/2008/site/images/logo-w3c-mobile-lg" alt="WC3 logo" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I look at the developers toolbar (by pressing f12) the HTML appears in a `<framset>` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Marrowbrook.com </title>  
    </head>
    <frameset rows="100%,*" border="0"> 
       <frame src="http://217.118.128.188/wotney//TestFiles/testpage.htm" frameborder="0" />  
       <frame frameborder="0" noresize />
     </frameset>
<!-- pageok -->
<!-- 02 -->
<!-- ->
</html>
```

Using Chrome, if I right click and View Source,  I see the above `<frameset>` code, but I can also right click and select View Frame Source where I can see the HTML as expected.

Can anyone tell me why I'm seeing this ?

Thanks.

Comment: So you're complaining that the IE9 developer console doesn't see into the frameset?

Comment: No Jan, that's not what I'm saying the dev console *does* see into the frameset. my question is - Why is it in a frameset ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could happen because your host name was bought with one provider, but you are hosting it on another - and you got a frame based redirect setup.

Answer (score 1):

What platform is your site hosted on? It looks like the server is doing something, because the src of the frame in the frameset points to your page. It could be some kind of 'preview mode' or something of the server/cms. So it looks like the server is using a default page with a frameset on it, that pulls your actual page into it after you deploy it

Comment: Thanks Dan,  I'll get the hosts of the website to have a look and see if they can shed some light on this for me !

Answer (score 1):

It also happens when the domain you are using to get to the site is set as "Masked" Forwarding.
Check with the domain manager on your hosting and remove masked forwarding.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but by removing the masking, my site is displayed in the address bar as an ip address instead of the domain name

Comment: I just solved a similar issue for a client of mine.
You'd have to have a primary domain set to the hosting. I see on the link you are using IIS and the ip is set as the domain name. http://217.118.128.188/. Is it a private server? You'd have to point the domain name to the server (ip). [link]http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/7620/adding-a-domain-name-in-microsoft-iis-7

Comment: Also you'd have to set the settings for the domain name in dns, to point to this ip.

Masked domain forwarding has a few issues. http://support.strikingly.com/knowledgebase/articles/199750-problems-with-masked-forwarding